# Location Manager won't display latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, latitude-longitude

I have an app which displays the longitude and the latitude of the users position. The application asks for the current location, and the latitude and the longitude displays in Xcode. But in the app, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
- (NSString *)deviceLocation {
    NSString *theLocation = 
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"latitude: %f longitude: %f", 
        locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, 
        locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    return theLocation;
}
```

In viewDidLoad:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters; // 100 m
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

NSLog(@"%@", [self deviceLocation]);
```

The problem is that the latitude and longitude -labels won't show the position.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann , this is the only code I have.

Comment: I think the problem is that I haven't set my labels to work with the locationmanager. Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you're not assigning your view controller as a *delegate* to  CLLocationManager.

You can do that via:

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

Right after you create your locationManager.

Then, you can update labels by having your view controller respond to the delegate method [`locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager%3adidUpdateLocations%3a).